# How can I go to the source code of elements in React native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, debugging, react-devtools

I'm writing code using React native and compiling from android studio with emulator. I do cntrl+m on the emulator and say "show inspector" and click on the elements, but it doesn't say on which line the code is. I also used dev-tool. I couldn't find it there either.The "<>" part appears to be unclickable.

My question is: How do I see the source code line and go to the main code when I click on the element(button,text....)?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use **Flipper**. This is a relatively new tool for react-native development and gives the best developer-experience for debugging react-native apps.

You can follow its documentation to see how it can be installed and used. It also gives you many different plugins to debug other parts of your code like Network, Performance, ...

[Flipper Documentation](https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started/react-native/)

Comment: Thank you. I uploaded it but the "source code" still doesn't show up. I can't see where and which line of code the "ui" element is written.